# Nagios NRPE plugin check_ad - Fixed

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, debian, nagios

i've reading about this problem much and trying to solve it on my own ways but still not luck.

I've running debian 7 as nagios server.
Problem is that i cant check state of my Active Directory Domain Controller (Win Server 2003) via this plugin based on nrpe scan - https://www.itefix.no/i2/check_ad

**192.168.1.12 - my Domain Controller**

NRPE on win server is working and listening correctly:

```
root@nagios:~ > check_nrpe -u -H 192.168.1.12 -p 5666
I (0,4,1,102 2013-07-15) seem to be doing fine...
```

but when i try to check AD via plugin it fails with this error:

```
root@nagios:~ > check_nrpe -u -H 192.168.1.12 -p 5666 -c check_ad
No handler for command: check_ad
```

---

By the way: i succesfuly run this command directly from win server:

Here is my NSClient++ config (I've enabled external script checking):
**C:\Program Files\NSClient++\nsclient.ini**

```
CheckExternalScripts = 1
```

and add this to bottom of file:

```
[NRPE Handlers]

check_ad=scripts\check_ad.exe --dc
check_ad_member=scripts\check_ad.exe –-member
```

Comment: Please don't edit your solution in your question, instead add it as an answer and accept it. It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions, and that way the question will be marked as "solved" in the system. Also, it will allow other users to give you credit with upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.
Looks like the nsclient has some troubles with running external commands.
I didnt want to dig it even more so now i am using 2 nrpe servers on my ADDC.
1 - Standart NSClient++ for collecting information about Uptime, Storage and othet thinks.
2 - nrpe_nt.0.8b - for monitoring Active Directory state

Just download it to server and install it via:

```
cd C:\nrpe_nt.0.8b-bin\bin\
NRPE_NT.exe -i
```

then i've changed listening port into config file 'nrpe.cfg' so it wouldnt conflict with nsclient++

**server_port=5667**

Added ip address of this machine: **server_address=192.168.1.12**

Allow connections from my nagios server: **allowed_hosts=192.168.1.250**

Allow command arguments: **dont_blame_nrpe=1**

And finally add command 'check_ad': **command[check_ad]=C:\nrpe_nt.0.8b-bin\bin\check_ad\check_ad.exe --member**

Answer (score -1):

Did you restart nsclient++ service when editing the configuration file?

Based on my experience, I prefer to use Winrpe https://www.itefix.no/i2/winrpe. I think it is less confusing than nsclient++.

Comment: Yes, of course i restarted it. By the way - i found solution and type it into question. Thanks for your help )

Comment: No problem. I had the same problem myself, I found NSClient++ hard to configure and I never got it to work so I decided to switch to Winrpe.